# Open print window without content

Tags: javascript

I have a button that opens a print window and set the content to be printed. The JS function is triggered when I click on a button. The issue is that the print window is being opened without the "content", so it just prints an empty page. If I come the print window and click on Control + P it works fine. How can I set the content before opening the print window?

```
function printApp(){
   var content = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
   content = content.replace('<input type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-success\" value=\" Print Application \" onclick=\"printApp();\">', '');                          
   var mywindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'height=600,width=800');

   mywindow.document.write('<html>');
   mywindow.document.write(content);
   mywindow.document.write('</html>');
   mywindow.document.close();
   mywindow.focus()
   mywindow.print();
   //mywindow.close();
   return true;                     
}
```

Comment: Don't see why ...it looks all fine

Comment: It works fine with Safari, but not with Firefox

Answer (score -1):

I know you want to dynamically set the print layout but you also seem to only want to remove one button from the content before printing. This can be achieved with CSS media queries:

```css
@media print {
    .btn.btn-success {
        display : none;
    } 
}
```

This will remove any button with `btn btn-success` classes from the DOM when the print window is active.

Comment: I think this is about show to remove the button from the content, but I still have the problem that the print is opening with empty page

Comment: I know, because you're opening it in a new tab without content. If you use the media query above without calling `window.open()`, it will work because it will open on the current page, which contains your printable content.

Comment: Still not working. Btw, the issue is happening with Firefox, but working fine with Safari